# Different Controllers in Angular based on authentication

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, controller, angularjs-scope

I have an app with a JWT authentication. I'm using $stateProvider to navigate into the app. From the server came, with the token, a boolean params (all came via json): isAdmin. Is there a possibility, if he is admin (isAdmin === true), to load a different Controller (and layout) from the one that would have to be non-administrator user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if (isAdmin === true)

1. Either use `$state` to navigate to a different state which is only for admins, something like `/admin` and have this code on top of the AdminController:

`if (!isAdmin) {$state.go('default.state');} 
// ...admin code goes here`

1. Using a same controller for both Admin and non-admin, let say CommonController, have different code based on condition

`if (admin === true) { // admin code goes here}
 else { // non admin code goes here }`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use $stateProvide to navigate to a different state which would load a completely new controller??